# How to build cvBlob for iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, compilation

Can someone may point me in the right direction how to build [cvBlob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/) as a static library (or even better as a framework) for iOS-Development?

Comment: Have you done this? If it possible can you send me the steps to do?

Comment: I recreated an OpenCV-C++-interface-based cvBlob myself for the company I founded, but unfortunately I can't share it. I suggest you to take a look at the [source code of cvBlob](https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/source/browse/#hg%2FcvBlob)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Cant I compile the exsisting cvblob C++ code and use it in ios, as ios supports C++? I would like to get your comments on it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first need to build OpenCV for iOS.  There are instructions on [this web site](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/02/building-opencv-for-iphone-in-one-click/).  You can then follow similar instructions on building cvBlob for iOS.  Basically, `cmake` will create an Xcode project for you, you'll just need to set the appropriate architecture.

You can see the script provided on the website simply includes the iOS SDK and changes `ARCH` so that it builds for the appropriate platform.  iOS devices need to be built for `armv6` and `armv7` while the simulator needs `i386`.

The script will build OpenCV as a static lib, then you should be able to replace OpenCV in the script with cvBlob's Xcode project.

Comment: Good starting point, but I can't get it working. Can you share a working build script for cvBlob?

Comment: `cmake -G Xcode` to build the Xcode project and then follow the `xcodebuild` from the script on the website for OpenCV.  Again, all they're doing is changing `ARCH` for the appropriate architecture.